# How to dynamically change HTML5 .webm file for iOS 5?

Tags: ipad, html, ios5, webm

I'm trying to use javascript to change the video file in browser on iOS 5.

Here is a image, when user click, it will call ChangeVideo function,

```
<table class=ControlLeft>
<tr><td colspan=1 class=GroupLabel>aaa</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class=MovieButton id=Cslide6><a href="#" onclick="ChangeVideo('Fire-presentation/m_slide1.webm')"><img class=ThumbImage src="Fire-presentation/thumbnails/slide6.png" alt="slide6"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is a div element which contains a .webm file,

```
<div id=container class=Container>
<video src=""Fire-presentation/m_slide1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
```

I used the following script to remove HTML content in the container, and create a new video element.

```
function ChangeVideo(path)
{
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.innerHTML = "";
    var myVideo = document.createElement("video");
    myVideo.src = path;
    myVideo.type = "video/webm";
    container.appendChild(myVideo);
    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
}
```

It works on my PC with Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't work on iPad 2 with iOS 5.0.1 , I did as
http://clubajax.org/ipad-bug-fix-for-dynamically-created-html5-video/
and 
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW5 suggest but neither works.

Is that possible to change the current playing video to another one in iPad 2 dynamically ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It possibly is, but [iOS doesn't support .webm](http://caniuse.com/webm) so it's not going to work with those particular videos whatever you do.